# Vue data within HTML attribute i.e src="{{images[0].src}}"

Tags: vue.js

If I am returning a data array, lets say:

```
data: {
images: [src: 'https://some.url/1.jpg']
}
```

And within the page I want to display the image, I'm not sure how I'd retrieve it:

```
<img src="{{images[0].src}}">
```

Is what I've attempted with no luck but hopefully shows what I'm attempting.

Comment: currently `images` looks like a weird/bad mix between a list and an object. Do you mean `{src: 'https:....'}`, `[{src: '...'}]`, or just `['https....']`, because depending on the answer how you reference it changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `:` to tell Vue to consider it an attribute.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Attributes

```
<img :src="images[0].src">
```

(You'll have to make `images` an actual array first, though.)

```
images: [{src: 'https://some.url/1.jpg'}]
```